# What is the best export format from AutoCAD -> Blender?

Tags: import, file-format

What format can AutoCAD export and Blender open in one go with no further conversion, just open it?

I have a project at which one party uses AutoCAD and we use blender. There are plenty of information out there about the import of a DWG file into blender. My question is a little bit different: What export format does CAD supports that blender can import without any further conversion? I have to tell the other party "export into XXX" and I must be able to open it (in blender). I'm aware this is not a CAD stackexchange, but I couldn't find any information about this out there.

Comment: Hi @morpheus05, please revise your question, as it stands it is framed subjectively.  Please read [ask] and [tour] for more info on this.  Help us to create a higher calibre of question.  Thanks

Comment: Hi @Merlin I don't know what you mean by "framed subjectively", maybe you can explain that a little bit more, which part of the post is not satisfactory.? Anyway, I moved my question to the beginning and the context part afterwards, maybe this makes it clearer?

Comment: Sorry I thought that this was clear from the links, but it turns out maybe not, apologies.  A subjective question is one where it invites opinion, it can vary in answer from person to person.  Here the use of "What is the best" in the title, makes this subjective.  Easy to fix with a quick edit, but worth bearing in mind that snappier titles will garner more views and hopefully better answers for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have always found **FBX** to be the most reliable way to export from Autodesk products for use in Blender. It tends to keep the correct dimensions, UVs, and Blender can estimate the materials quite well (albeit with some junk nodes thrown in for maximum compatibility).

That being said, it seems [Autodesk has been removing FBX exporting from AutoCAD](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad-forum/autocad-2019-removed-fbx-import-and-export/td-p/7904421), so I don't know if that will be the best option for you if are using or plan to use AutoCAD 2019. I have heard from an interview with Ton Roosendaal that Autodesk has been removing FBX because it has become too accessible to 3rd parties, and so they can't make as much money leaving it available in their software. A shame, if true, but there could be many other reasons we aren't privy to.